# How can I plot Histogram for discrete data using python matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, histogram

Here is the data, How can I plot a histogram using matplotlib on this Discrete data.

```
X   F
3   3
4   3
5   5
6   3
7   4
8   4
9   3
10  4
11  2
12  2
13  3
14  1
15  2
16  5
17  2
18  1
19  2
20  1
```

Comment: `df.set_index('X').plot.bar()`?

Comment: This might not be the most optimal, but here's the simplest solution: store the values as so: `values = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(f[i])]`, and use the hist() module with this array of values. Each value `x[i]` in `x` is repeated `f[i]` times.

Comment: Since this is already in a dataframe: `df.plot(kind='bar', x='X', ec='k', width=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is already a histogram (don't need to bin any observations here, is that right?), so I suppose you just need to plot it.

```
# First read in the data into a dataframe in this case.
data = """
3   3
4   3
5   5
6   3
7   4
8   4
9   3
10  4
11  2
12  2
13  3
14  1
15  2
16  5
17  2
18  1
19  2
20  1""".split();
data = list(map(int, data))
data = pd.DataFrame({'X': data[::2], 'F': data[1::2]})

# Use matplotlib to draw a bar chart. Draw it with histogram style.
plt.bar(data.X, data.F, align='edge', width=1, edgecolor='k');
```

[image: histogram example]